# How to run nightwatch test cases in sequence / in series?

Tags: windows, batch-file, nightwatch.js

I want to run my nightwatch test case with several browsers, but not in parallel. I cannot do in parallel because each test require a login / session with a same username. I have created a batch file which looks like this:

```
nightwatch testcase.js --reporter html-reporter.js -e ch
nightwatch testcase.js --reporter html-reporter.js -e ie
pause
```

However, after executing test with chrome (ch) it does not continue to the next line (test with IE) although the test is successful.

I thought it was an issue with nightwatch, so I modified the batch file to look like this

```
testcase-CH.bat
testcase-IE.bat
pause
```

with every batch file contains a single nightwatch line, but it did not work too.

At this point, I'm not sure whether this is a nightwatch issue or batch file issue. But I have created some batch file before (not with nightwatch) and it executes every commmand on the batch file.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Is whatever nightwatch is a batch file. If so see `call /?`.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard It works. Thank you! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Noodles thank you also for your comment! But I understand Gerhard's comment better and I can only accept one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running batch-files from a batch file, you need to use call to let it run in the current batch session else it will open a new instance and never return to the current window, therefore we need to `call` the batch files:

```
call nightwatch testcase.js --reporter html-reporter.js -e ch
call nightwatch testcase.js --reporter html-reporter.js -e ie
pause
```